# C++ Overload operator ==

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have created a class `Location`. This class is a parent class for classes `City` and `Village`. The `Location` class is abstract. I have created a `vector<Location*> locations`, which contains cities and villages. `Location` contains a name. If two locations have the same name, it means that they are same. I have overloaded operator `==` for `Location`.

```
bool operator==(const Location& lhs) const
{
    return (this->mName.compare(lhs.mName) == 0);
}
```

If I want to add some location into the `vector`, I firstly check if this location does not exist. I use this function:

```
bool checkLocation(Location* l) {
    return find(locations.begin(), locations.end(), l) != locations.end();
}
```

For example, if I want to add some city into the `vector`, the method above still returns `false`, which means, that `Location` does not exist. But in the `vector` there is a city with same name. Can you tell me please, where is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Note that the vector stores *pointers*, so the `find` call will compare *pointers* and not use your `operator==` function.

Comment: You should have debugged your `operator==` somehow, to see if it's even called.

Comment: @juanchopanza: `std::find_if` doesn't take *binary* predicate (it doesn't need to, as it doesn't make sense!).

Comment: @Nawaz Yes of course! I meant unary...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your vector stores pointers, `std::find` will compare the pointers, which will not invoke `Location::operator==()` to compare the elements.

You need to use `std::find_if` along with lambda:

```
return std::find_if(locations.begin(), 
                    locations.end(), 
                    [l](Location  const *x) {
                         return *l == *x;      //invoke operator=
                     }) != locations.end();
```

The lambda dereferences the pointers, and then uses `==` invoke the `Location::operator=`.

If the location objects are not huge, I would advise you to use `std::vector<Location>` instead of `std::vector<Location*>`. If you use `std::vector<Location>`, then you can use `std::find` and the code will be simplied.

Even if location objects are huge, it is better to use smart pointer instead of raw pointer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I get a compilation error: no matching function for call to find_if (I have included <algorithm>).

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'find_if(std::vector<Location*>::iterator, std::vector<Location*>::iterator, checkLocation(Location*)::__lambda0)

Comment: @PSglass: I believe you're doing something wrong. Post the code at pastebin or ideone.com.

Comment: Sorry, my fail. My compiler was not supported lambda functions. I checked "some checkbox" and it works now. I'm not a C++ programmer, I'm programming in Java normally, so I am sorry for my fail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing `Location*` in the `vector`. The `find` algorithm will compare the values of the `pointer`, not the name in the `Location` object. You have to provide custom comparer to the algorithm.